# Problem with model binding in file input type

Tags: html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, bootstrap-5

I'm working on an Asp.Net Core MVC project. In my model, I have an `IFormFile` property. When I use a simple input tag It works fine, But on using the file input plugin in [this](https://plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo) URL, It fails to do the model binding on the IFormFile property! Has anyone faced the same problem?

Here is the input tag

```
<input id="input-b2" name="input-b2" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false" asp-for="ImageFile" accept="image/jpeg">
```

The IFormfile property has annotations of `Required`, `Display`, and `NotMapped`

Comment: Hi @ahamad zooghi, how is your backend code? The name attribtue here is not correct, are you sure you used the same html code before and works fine?  If you add the `name="input-b2"` , the backend parameter should be like `IFormFile input-b2`, but this parameter name is a wrong name.  You can see it even cannot compile susseccfully.

Comment: Hi dear @Rena! You are right. The problem is when you use asp-for in an HTML tag, You don't need to use the name attribute for binding.

Comment: Hi @ahamad zooghi, I have shared the correct answer below. pls remember to accept as an answer and it will also help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use name attribute, it will override the `asp-for` generated name. For your scenario, you just need to remove it:

```
<input id="input-b2" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false" asp-for="ImageFile" accept="image/jpeg">
```